# Don't have Locals window on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, window, local

When I click on Debug -> Windows ->, I havn't the Locals Windows, I have only Breakpoints, Exception Settings, Output, Show Diagnostic Tools, Immediate. How can I add the Locals window?

Comment: Did you try that during debugging?

Answer (score 2):

Run your project. Most of the contents of Debug>>Windows only appear when you're running code

When stopped:

[image]

When running:

[image]

Comment: when I click start it's opening the Output window but it's doesn't show me when show me the continue and stop

Comment: Try doing a Reset Window Layout on the Window menu (as in the Window menu on the menu bar, not the Windows sub entry in the Debug menu). It's quite easy to accidentally drag the tray containing Locals etc out of its docking station and then close it